# How to resolve Shift/Reduce conflict in simple grammar

Tags: jflex, cup

The grammar is as follows:

```
terminal TERM1,TERM2;
non terminal  entry, sector, unit_a, unit_b;

entry ::= sector unit_b;    
sector ::= unit_a sector | unit_a;    
unit_a ::= TERM1 TERM1;    
unit_b ::= TERM1 TERM2;
```

When i try to generate the parser with jcup, I'm getting the following warnings

```
Warning : *** Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #1
  between sector ::= unit_a (*) 
  and     unit_a ::= (*) TERM1 TERM1 
  under symbol TERM1
  Resolved in favor of shifting.

Warning : *** Production "sector ::= unit_a " never reduced
```

How can i find what causes this conflict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shift/reduce Error with Cup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185601/shift-reduce-error-with-cup)